# Why does this condition equate to false?

Tags: c#, checkbox, contextmenu, windows-store-apps

With a breakpoint on the "if" line of this code:

```
if ((ckbx.Content != null) && (!ckbx.Content.ToString().Contains("(Empty list)")))
{
    string groupName = ckbx.Content.ToString();
    var contextMenu = new PopupMenu();

    contextMenu.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Edit this Group", contextMenuCmd => Frame.Navigate

    (typeof(LocationGroupCreator), groupName)));

    contextMenu.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Delete this Group", async (contextMenuCmd) =>
    {
        await SQLiteUtils.DeleteGroupAsync(groupName); 
    }));

    await contextMenu.ShowAsync(args.GetPosition(this));
}
```

...ckbx.Content is "(Empty list)", but the condition is seen as false - the condition fails. Why?

Comment: What's the type of ckbx.Content?

Comment: It appears to be working properly.  first clause is true and 
"(Empty list)".Contains("Empty list") is true, but you threw a ! in front, so it's false

Comment: Using a debugger is very helpful in a situation like this.

Comment: I was using a debugger - that's how I knew what the value of Content was. The problem was I wasn't using my eyes, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...ckbx.Content is "(Empty list)", but the condition is seen as false - the condition fails. Why?

Your condition has the [logical negation operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2kd6eb2.aspx) (`!`) negating the results of `Contains`:

```
 (!ckbx.Content.ToString().Contains("(Empty list)"))
```

As such, if the content contains "(Empty list)", `Contains` will  return `true`, and the `!` will make it `false`, which makes the condition fail.

Comment: True; now I wonder why it worked until recently; I'm sure I didn't touch that code...

Comment: Ah, now I see - that IS how it's supposed to work (with the "Not empty list"); after returning to this project following a long hiatus from it, I forgot the reason for not showing the Edit or Delete if the item has not been created yet (in which case the content is "Empty list"...)

Answer (score 2):

`(ckbx.Content != null)` is true

`(!ckbx.Content.ToString().Contains("(Empty list)")` is false - you just said it WAS the empty list... and this checks that is ISN'T the empty list (thanks to the "!" in the front - "!" means NOT) .

true && false, of course, equates to false